# How to automatically link local git branches to remote ones?

Tags: git, github, version-control

To rebase my branches quickly, I have created a .gitconfig alias for rebasing from master and force pushing

`rb = "pull origin master --rebase"`

and one for force pushing

`fp = "push -f"`

I chain these in the shell using `git rb && git fp`. which is useful for executing the two commands together with autocomplete in my shell.

This works unless the remote branch is ahead of my local branch.

I wanted to add another alias for ensuring that the local branch I am on is up to date with remote, but without having to specify the branch name.

If I set

```
[pull]
    default = current
```

will this allow me to do something like

`up = git pull --rebase` without having to specify the branch?

Ideally I would like to string together

`git up && git rb && git fp`

to ensure the branch is up to date from remote, rebased from master and then force push it.

I thought setting the `[pull] default = current` above, it would work... but it does not seem to, as `git pull --rebase` gives me this failure

```
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-pull(1) for details.

git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> chore/prs
```

Comment: (1) There is no `pull.default` (Git ignores any setting it does not expect, so you can *set* this, it just does nothing). (2) Use `--set-upstream-to` as in Git's advice here. This must be done once per branch, although most cases of *creating* local branch names based on `origin/<samename>` do it automatically anyway, so it's not a big deal. (3) I recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely: it's just `git fetch` followed by a second command (normally either merge or rebase) but you plan to do *two* post-`fetch` commands, so you might as well just do them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @LeGEC hint to use  `push --force-with-lease` you could also update you branch before force pushing by running

```
git pull --rebase origin \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\"
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! https://media.giphy.com/media/cdr4V05plfxv2/giphy.gif

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is in the message output by git : the last line tells you how to link your local branch to a remote branch.

---

Also : you should use `push --force-with-lease` instead of `push -f`.
see for example [this link (on atlassian)](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/)

Comment: I edited my answer, the initial message about "don't use `-f`" didn't work with a rebase workflow.

Comment: Great to know about this, this is really important. I have made this mistake a few times lately where I have overwritten remote changes and this will at least super reinforce that it won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can **create a shell script** in your local repo, every time you want to execute the serial commands, just run the shell script.

**E.g.** The test.sh file can do `git pull --rebase && git pull origin master && git push -f`.

```
#!/bin/sh
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

(git pull origin $current_branch --rebase && git pull origin master --rebase && git push origin $current_branch -f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great idea, but it can be solved without scripts as you can see in the answer by Daniel above.